# Hotel Royal Barriere - как правильно отобразить на русском?

Tags: переводы

Нашла Hôtel Barrière Le Royal Deauville - как его правильно транскрибировать?

У автора что-то вроде гостиница "Роял-Барьер" и далее казино "Барьер Довиль". (Дела французские стародавние, так заведения назывались при открытии.)

И "роял" смущает, и "барьер"...

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Уж не Роял надо, а Рояль.

Comment: В приключениях Бонда, в экранизациях и разных перводах, варианты: Роял, Рояль, Руаяль, Ройал, Ройяль...

Comment: Точно, Галина, Руаяль будет ближе всего к оригиналу по звучанию!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Отель "Барьер лё Рояль-Довиль"** Так как слово французское, то "л" мягкое, а Довиль - это коммуна во Франции. *Лё* (или *ля*) - это из какой местности и традиционно ставится через пробелы.

Можно совсем русифицированный вариант **Заслон королевского Довиля**, но тогда и гостиницу можно не опознать.

Comment: В "Барьере" уверен? )))

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova И повторюсь: если именно транскрибировать, надо Р**уа**яль.

Comment: Тёмыч, хозяйке (= автору) - на заметку!